# Why has grayscale a higher bitrate than YUV with H.265/HEVC?

Tags: ffmpeg, compression, colorspace, h265

For compression purposes, I am re‐encoding a grayscale video to the H.265/HEVC codec. Although the input video is more or less perfectly grayscale in aspect, it is provided in the `yuv420p` pixel format. So I thought that mapping the video to the `gray` pixel format would reduce file size further. I was expecting this, not only because `gray` uses 8 bits per pixel while `yuv420p` uses 12 (according to `ffmpeg -pix_fmts`), but also because stripping noisy data (irrelevant color information) would help compression.

To my surprise, the opposite happened: the output video in `gray` is about 14 % larger than the output video in `yuv420p`!

---

As an example, I measured the byte size with a 60‐second footage, which I encoded as follows :

```
ffmpeg -i in.h264 \
    -filter:V 'crop=960:720:160:0, format=gray, format=yuv420p' \
    -c:V libx265 -crf 26 -preset medium \
  out-gray-yuv.h265
```

I tried several filter chains (I was also cropping the video):

- nothing (output file `out.h265`),
- turning the video to `gray` (output file `out-gray.h265`)
- turning the video to `gray`, then back to `yuv420p` (output file `out-gray-yuv.h265`) — as hinted at by [that answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/21642).

(I also tried the hue filter, like this: `hue=s=0`, but it is apparently subsumed by converting the video to `gray`. Also, using the `-pix_fmt` option appears to be equivalent to appending a format filter)

```
BYTES      NAME                FFPROBE
14972779   in.h264             h264 (Main), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
 3043717   out-gray.h265       hevc (Rext), gray(tv),                 960x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 25 tbc
 2670564   out.h265            hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv),              960x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 25 tbc
 2662991   out-gray-yuv.h265   hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv),              960x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 25 tbc
```

It appears that `out-gray-yuv` is very slightly smaller than `out`, which is not surprising (it could come from the input video not being perfectly grayscale yet). However, it is also about 14 % smaller than `out-gray`, which I cannot explain.

---

Why do I observe these results? What should I do to benefit from grayscale compression with H.265?

Comment: Imna hazard a guess and say out-gray.h265 doesn’t use chroma sub sampling, and isn’t just the y’ component, maybe? Maybe it’s 411? I don’t understand why out-gray-Yuv would be 420, either; it shouldn’t have a chrominance component — it should just be black and white.

Comment: encoding videos can be quirky. A different combination of preset and crf values might give you totally different results!

Also I imagine that the libx265 encoder was primarily optimized for yuv420/yuv420p10/color  formats. You might just be running into some slightly substandard behavior.

One thing you can try is keep the yuv420p format, but explicitly remove the chroma components with `lutrgb="g=0:b=0"` and see what happens.

Comment: I consistently observe this. @JasonConrad the `gray` pixel format doesn’t even have a chroma to sub-sample. It’s really just the Y component (or Y', I don’t know exactly) at 8 bits per pixel. Whereas the `yuv420p` is 12 bits per pixel (Y at 8b/px, U at 8b/4px, V at 8b/4px). This is documented by `ffmpeg -pix_fmts`. As far as I understand, the encoding of `out-gray-yuv` is just the same as that of `out-gray` with four additional null bits per pixel. So I guess it’s just that H.265 compression algorithms/settings have not been optimized for 8bit-pixels. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Chris The video filter `lutrgb=g=0:b=0` imposes RGB instead of YUV, and removes the green and blue components, leaving the picture in redscale. I guess you rather meant `lutyuv=u=128:v=128` (hinted by `man ffmpeg-filters`), which cancels the chroma components (while keeping these null components in the output). I just tested it, it is exactly the same (bit-equal) as the filter chain `format=gray, format=yuv420p` which I was using in the question.

Comment: Right you are! I've learned a bit more about color in the year since I replied. Sometimes I wonder if ffmpeg's automatic format conversion filter insertion does too much.   It makes things much easier to get working most of the time, but in this case it automatically inserts a format conversion filter to rgb24 before `lutrgb=g=0:b=0`. If I was forced to be explicit about fmt conversions I probably would have re-thought what I was doing. Just some musings. Anyway, thanks for correcting me!